ROS melodic/ How do I make the local planner as straight as possible
I am currently using ROS Melodic and the move_base package for navigation. I am utilizing the A* global planner and DWA local planner and would like the vehicle to follow a path passing through specific waypoints. These waypoints are aligned in a straight line, and since there are no obstacles, the A* global planner generates a global path that is almost perfectly straight. However, due to the characteristics of the local planner and variables such as the costmap values, the local planner often creates a slightly winding local path rather than following the straight global path generated by A*.
My question is: How can I ensure that the local path aligns as closely as possible to the straight global path? I would like to continue using the DWA planner in case obstacles appear, but I also want the path to be as straight as possible.
Should I adjust the move_base parameters, or are there other methods I should consider? I would greatly appreciate your advice.
Thank you in advance.
